# TIdMessageParts.CountParts Returns 0

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I'm trying to pull multipart emails in MIME format from an IMAP server using Indy 10.5.5 in Delphi 2010.  These are the lines of code that I'm having trouble with are below, where I instatiate the curMessage object, retrieve a message into it, and then call CountParts:

```
var
  curMessage: TIdMessage;   
  IMAP4: TIdIMAP4;
  msgIndex: Integer;

begin
  ...
  curMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  IMAP4.Retrieve(msgIndex, curMessage);
  curMessage.MessageParts.CountParts;
  //code that checks counts
  //and 
end;
```

I then have some code that checks the various count properties of curMessage.MessageParts (i.e. TextPartCount). However, the CountPart procedure isn't returning anything, because the `Count` property referenced in the procedure block is 0, even though I've verified that the message is retrieved and placed into the curMessage.

One thing I've noticed, and haven't gotten to the bottom of yet, is that IsMsgSinglePartMime is coming back as true, even though all the messages on the server have `Content-Type: multipart/mixed;`.

Any help would be really appreciated.

What am I missing here? I can provide more code if needed,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the actual email data, it is difficult to say for sure exactly why the data is not where you expect it to be.  But if the `TIdMessage.IsMsgSinglePartMime` is getting set to True then that means that either:

1. `TIdMessage.Encoding` is `meMIME` but `TIdMessage.MIMEBoundary.Count` is 0, meaning there was no MIME `boundary` value detected in the top-level `Content-Type` header.  If the `Content-Type` is a `'multipart/...'` type, a `boundary` is required.  If it is present, it is likely malformed in a way that prevented Indy from parsing it.
2. `TIdMessage.Encoding` is `mePlainText` but `TIdMessage.ContentTransferEncoding` is either `'base64'` or `'quoted-printable'`.

In either case, if there is body content present then it would end up in the `TIdMessage.Body` property if it is textual data, otherwise it would end up in the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` as an attachment instead.  Since `TIdMessage.MessageParts.Count` is 0 in your case, the data is either in `TIdMessage.Body`, or is got discarded.

You may want to consider [upgrading to a newer Indy version](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx).  The version shipped with D2010 is pretty old, and there have been fixes/changes made to `TIdIMAP4` and `TIdMessage` (and its internal parsers) in recent years.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. There is a processable boundary, and some further testing this morning showed that some messages are being processed correctly. It just happened that the first few messages in the folder I'm processing all had the same issue.

I found a line break in the header of the messages that are causing the problem. IdMessageClient.ReceiveHeader is only returning the lines of the header before the line break. I'm not sure if this is handled better in later versions of Indy, but it sounds like IMAP has consistency problems that POP doesn't and maybe I'm just running into those.

Comment: Email headers and body content are separated by a blank line (more accurately, by a `CRLF+CRLF` sequence, though Indy also supports `LF+LF`, `CRLF+LF` and `LF+CRLF`). If the headers have an extra erroneous line break, there is nothing Indy (or any other email parser) can do about that. That is just how email works.